# I want my JavaFX program to play a video when a button is pressed but only audio plays

Tags: button, video, javafx, event-handling, media

I'm new to JavaFX and I need to play a video when a button is pressed, but for some reason I can't quite understand, only the sound is played. Here's my code:

```
package trailer;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Trailer extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

    Button button;

    BackgroundImage image;

    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(new Media(getClass().getResource("videonamehere.mp4").toExternalForm()));
    MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(player);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("title content");
        button = new Button("button name");
        button.setOnAction(this);

        Label label = new Label("label content");
        label.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);

        VBox layout = new VBox();
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(200));
        layout.setSpacing(20);
        layout.getChildren().add(button);
        layout.getChildren().add(label);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 1920, 1080);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(Trailer.class.getResource("cssfilename.css").toExternalForm();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event){
        if(event.getSource() == button){
            player.play();
        }
    }
}
```

To clarify, the interface with the button, the label, and the CSS effects does show up, but when I press the button only the sound from the video plays.

Comment: Did you add `mediaView` to the scene somewhere???

Comment: I think not... Should I add it as a child of the VBox, just like the button and the label?

Comment: Ok, I added it to the VBox as a child and it worked! Thank you very much!